# Delphi: intercept SWbemServices.ExecQuery error

Tags: vb.net, delphi, error-handling, wmi, msdn

I'm implementing a WMI interface in Delphi VCL, I managed to have it working, but I'm now trying to make it a little more robust.

The portion of code I'm working on is this:

```
var
    FWbemServices: ISWbemServices;
    WMIObject: ISWbemObjectSet;
    WMISQLQuery: String;
    FCount: Integer;
...
    FWbemServices := FWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\CIMV2', '', '', '', '', 0, nil);
    WMIObject := FWbemServices.ExecQuery(WMISQLQuery, 'WQL', wbemFlagReturnImmediately, nil);
...
    FCount := WMIObject.Count;
...
```

It completely works when WMISQLQuery contains a valid WMI query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard
```

But if the query is wrong, for example misspelling the class name, when trying to access WMIObject.Count it suddently gives me an EOleException "Invalid query" which I can't handle by surrounding it with a try .. except block.

I checked [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393866(v=vs.85).aspx) which clearly states:

> After the completion of the **ExecQuery** method, the [Err](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf5ze0e(v=vs.84).aspx) object can
>   contain one of the error codes in the following list.
>
> **wbemErrAccessDenied** - 2147749891 (0x80041003)
>
> Current user does not have the permission to view the result set.
>
> **wbemErrFailed** - 2147749889 (0x80041001)
>
> Unspecified error.
>
> **wbemErrInvalidParameter** - 2147749896 (0x80041008)
>
> Invalid parameter was specified.
>
> **wbemErrInvalidQuery** - 2147749911 (0x80041017)
>
> Query syntax is not valid.
>
> **wbemErrInvalidQueryType** - 2147749912 (0x80041018)
>
> Requested query language is not supported.
>
> **wbemErrOutOfMemory** - 2147749894 (0x80041006)
>
> Not enough memory to complete the operation.

The fact is, I'm not able to access the Err object in any way.

I still remember the Err object when I was using it in VB like:

```
On Error Resume Next
...
DoSomething
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
...
```

I just would like to be able to use it in Delphi.

The fun fact is that in the imported WMI TLB I do have those constants ready for use.

### **UPDATE, partially solved**

Maybe I was just to tired (it was 3:25AM January, 1st) and needed some rest to see how the whole thing acted. I'm not saying I solved it, since **I did not find the way to access the Err object from Delphi**, but in this partitular case I was able to handle the exception. Unfortunately I cannot discern them since the class is always EOleException and the Exception.Message is translated to system language, but at least I don't have an unhandled exception.

I've shared a small project on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzma12o7pndmzyx/MicroWMI.zip?dl=0), it does not contain binaries, just the minimum required Delphi files to be compiled, you can also check it on [VirusTotal](https://virustotal.com/it/file/c8550f8f7d527f3d1818148d5294d5a464a109748229bf51e04e8faa5addb448/analysis/1483272835/).

This example will test a good and a bad WMI query.

**I still would appreciate if someone finds a way to get information from the Err object.**

Comment: Could you provide complete source code reproducing the problem. For me it fails on ExecQuery method with 'Invalid class' exception

Comment: Without wbemFlagReturnImmediately flag it raises exception on ExecQuery, do you need it?

Comment: In response to EugeneK's both comments: the wbemFlagReturnImmediately does not change the way the function acts in my case since **it always returns a valid pointer**.I provided a link to a source code you can test, but as stated in my update this will only handle the exception, not giving me any way to find out which error caused it. I still need to access the Err object to identify what kind of error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOLEException has ErrorCode property, so you can use something like this

```
except
  on E: EOLEException do
  begin
    if E.ErrorCode = HRESULT(wbemErrInvalidQuery) then
    begin
      // do something
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: **Thank you**, this it the correct solution! Didn't check the EOleException's members, usually E.Message and E.ClassName are enough for me and this did limit my field of view. Thank you again, you made my day.